# android: Circular inheritance for passing validate/data from dynamic ViewPager fragments to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am facing a problem and would like some insights on how I can go about solving this. Here’s a brief description

**Components description:**

1. An `Activity` with a `ViewPager`, and two buttons:

   - `Add fragment` button => Adds new fragment to ViewPager with same layout
   - `Continue` button => If user fields are validated in all fragments, goes to next screen

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InputData mfirstProfileData;
    private ArrayList<InputData> mEditProfilesDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    private EditProfilePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private Button AddButton;
    private Button ContinueButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);
        mFirstProfileData = new InputData();        
        ...

        mDotTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true);
        mPagerAdapter = new EditProfilePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                mViewPager, mDotTabLayout, mFirstProfileData);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        mAddProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ){ 
                // TODO: validate data and save in List<InputData> 
            addProfile(EditProfileFragment.newInstance(getNextPageNumber(), new InputData());          
            }
        });

        mContinueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ){ 
                // TODO: validate data iff one EditProfileFragment and save in List<InputData> 
            sendToServer();          
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    public void addProfile(Fragment fragment) {
        mPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment);
    }

    public void deleteProfile () {
        mPagerAdapter.deleteFragment();
    }

}
```

2. A `FragmentPagerAdapter` responsible for fragment(s) initialization, takes care of dynamic Addition/Deletion of fragments

```
public class EditProfilePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabLayout mDotTabLayout;

    public EditProfilePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager viewPager, TabLayout tabLayout, InputData firstProfileInputData) {
        super(fm);
        fragments.add(EditProfileFragment.newInstance(0, firstProfileInputData));
        mViewPager = viewPager;
        mDotTabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    public void addFragment (Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        mDotTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragments.size() - 1);
    }

    public void deleteFragment () {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
            fragments.remove(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        mDotTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragments.size() - 1);
    }
    ...
}
```

3. A profile `Fragment` with 5 user input fields (`EditTexts`, `RadioButtons`, `Dialogs`) and one button:

   - Delete => Deletes the current fragment from the ViewPager

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ... // bunch of user input fields
    private InputData mInputData;
    private int mPosition;
    private FloatingActionButton mDeleteBtn;

    public static EditProfileFragment newInstance(int position, InputData inputData) {
        EditProfileFragment fragment = new EditProfileFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
        args.putParcelable(KEY_NEW_INPUT_DATA, inputData);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mPosition = getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);
            mInputData = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_NEW_INPUT_DATA);
        }
        ...
        // Take user input and save as mInputData.setName() etc.
        ...

        mDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO: send mInputData back to ParentActivity so it can be removed from the List<InputData>
                ((ParentActivity) getActivity()).deleteProfile();
            }
        });


    }
    ...



}
```

**Use Case:**

- A user comes in the Activity with 1 fragment to start with.
- User fills out the fields in the fragment, some required ones (basic validation), he can either press `Add` in activity to add another profile fragment with same input fields.
- Upon addition, User can also delete a fragment if he wants to, with the delete button is present in each fragment itself.

IMO, the triggers I have identified to pass the data along to activity are:

- `Add button`
  If the user fills the current fragment and presses the add button to get another edit profile fragment, we can `validate` the data coming from the current fragment in the activity and save it in `List<InputData>`, if validation is successful, if not, we `setError()` on the field which is missing from the required ones.
- `Continue button`: If the user only has 1 profile (since adding another profile isn't mandatory), we can check for validation if the user presses the button before going on the next screen
- `Delete button`: If user deletes a profile, the activity is notified so that we can remove that profile data from `List<InputData>.remove(mInputData)`

I want to synchronize validation of user input and sending of user data from each fragment to the parent activity

So at the end when the user presses `Continue`, I get a `List<InputData>`, one for each fragment user created. Similarly, if the user presses `Delete` on any fragment, the `List<InputData>` gets updated to remove that fragment’s data.

**How should I go about orchestrating this?**

I tried implementing an interface (both in `ParentActivity` and `EditProfileFragment` and listening to `onAddButtonPressed()` (Add button in activity) and `onDeleteButtonPressed()` (Delete button in fragment) and ended up getting a circular inheritance. Any help is appreciated!